# How can I pause/continue a timer in EditorWindow?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnGUI()
    {
        pauseCounting = GUILayout.Toggle(pauseCounting, "Pause timer");
        Timer();
    }
```

Then:

```
private void Timer()
    {
        if (stopCounting == false)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Count Each:", countTime + " Secs");

            if (waitForUI)
                timeToCount = nextCountTime - EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup;

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Next Count:", timeToCount.ToString() + " Sec");
            if (waitForUI == false)
            {
                timeToCount = 30;
                waitForUI = true;
            }

            this.Repaint();

            if (EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup > nextCountTime)
            {
                nextCountTime = EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup + countTime;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Counting:", countTime + " Secs");
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Next Count:", countToSave.ToString() + " Sec");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I'm using now EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup and if I change the flag stopCounting to true then back to false it will calculate using the EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup and will not continue from the point it was stopped. I want that if stopCounting is true then false again continue the time from the last pause it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your class, add a field to record the total ticking time:

```
double timerRecord;
```

in your onEnable, init it:

```
timerRecord = EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup;
```

in your OnGUI(), add some logic to check the 'restart' action:

```
var shouldStop = GUILayout.Toggle(stopCounting, "Pause timer");
if(!shouldStop && stopCounting)
{
    // in this case, you restarted the timer.
    timerRecord = EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup;
}
stopCounting = shouldStop;
Timer();
```

and finally in your Time(), replace all 'EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup' with 'timerRecord', and at the end of it, update the value of 'timerRecord' with 'EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup'.

```
timerRecord = EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup;
```